# Shell Script execution donot exit

Tags: shell

While I am executing the shell script as a root user it executes perfectly but when i execute the shell script as normal user (not as root) then shell script executes continuously. Is the root user or normal user determines the execution of shell Script?

```
#!/bin/sh

s=$1      

pro=`ps -ef | grep $s | grep -v grep | grep -v test3.sh | wc -l`

if [ $pro -eq 0 ] 
then
        echo "Service $s is DOWN..."
        echo "Service $s is DOWN..." >> processlogs.txt
        echo "Starting Service $s..."
        echo "Starting Service $s..." >> processlogs.txt
        java -jar clientApplication.jar $s &

else
        echo "Service $s is Running..."
        echo "Service $s is Running..." >> processlogs.txt

fi
```

Comment: Can you publish your script ?

Comment: Publish also the permissions of the script.

Comment: When you say executes continuously, do you mean it consumes CPU continuously, or it just hangs and does absolutely nothing?  Either way, if you're on a Unix-like system, you can use `top` and press `f` to select fields, then add the "WCHAN" field to see what function your processes are waiting inside.

Comment: If you say `set -x` at the top of your script, it will print each command it executes.  This may help track down the problem.  Also, if you say `set -e` it will stop on errors, which is always a good idea.

Comment: executes continuously means it executes the command "java -jar clientApplication.jar $s" continuously and hence cannot exit from the script. But there is no problem in else condition.

Comment: it should not depend on the user if the script manages to push the java process in the backgroupd orr not. I rather assume that something in the `$1` manages to swallow the `&`. It might help to quote it, e.g. `java -jar clientApplication.jar "$s" &`. Then, what value has `$1` actually when you call it and it hangs ?

Comment: $1 is just string. In this case SMSC1410, SMSC1420 and SMSC1430. I tried that quote but that doesnot work.

Comment: @Suniel: You need to provide more information. Which exact command are you running, and what happens?

Comment: This scripts checks if the services are running or not. If the process is running print the information, if not run the services. clientApplication.jar is the simple program that takes services as arguments and print inside while(true) loop.In my case the operation cannot exit from the if condition.